# Click event with jQuery('body') works but jQuery(document) is not. Why?

Tags: jquery

I have a case where a click event with `jQuery('body')` works, but with `jQuery(document)` it isn't. Why?

This works:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.mySelector', function(){
    alert('hello');
})
```

vs.

This doesn't work

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mySelector', function(){
    alert('hello');
})
```

Comment: If there is a click event handler on `<body>` that calls `event.stopPropagation()`, then the event won't reach the `document`. There's not enough context to provide any sort of canonical answer though

Comment: How do I find and remove that specific event.stopPropagation() event in order to verify your idea? 
Also, other click events with jQuery(document) work just fine, only this one with a specific selector doesn't.
Regarding context: I can't give more, because I have no idea how to narrow it down. Maybe I should delete the question?

Comment: It's your code, can you not do a global search for _"stopPropagation"_? Event handlers that `return false` also stop event bubbling. Here's a demo showcasing how events can bubble or be stopped ~ https://jsfiddle.net/rc3sgqyz/

Comment: "It's your code". Yes and no. I work on a WooCommerce plugin. Most of the code I have to deal with is not mine. And I need to make mine as globally compatible as possible. Thanks for the demo!